# How to turn on JPA logging

Tags: openjpa

To turn on JPA logging as per the link [here](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.3/apache-openjpa-1.0.3/docs/manual/ref_guide_logging_openjpa.html)

This needs to be done where? in persistence.xml?

```
<property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs to be done in the persistence.xml, yes.

Answer (score 2):

```
-Dopenjpa.Log=DefaultLevel=WARN,Runtime=INFO,Tool=INFO,SQL=TRACE
```

It can also be set as a JVM property.